# Tabbar in the body gives error message overflowing

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
import '../constants/constants.dart';

class BooksPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const BooksPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BooksPage> createState() => _BooksPageState();
}

class _BooksPageState extends State<BooksPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(
        
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  "Hello",
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                ),
                const Text(
                  "Name Surname",
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
               TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                    fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(244, 243, 243, 243),
                    filled: true,
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                    hintText: "Search the book",
                    contentPadding:
              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 17),
                    enabledBorder: searchBox(),
                    focusedBorder: searchBox(),
                    errorBorder: searchBox(),
                    disabledBorder: searchBox(),
                  )),
                  SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      "My books",
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("see more", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),))
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 260,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: 3,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                          width: 190,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              color: Colors.red,
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage("assets/images/pride.jpg",),
                                fit: BoxFit.fill
                              ),
                          ), 
                        );
                      }),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 30,),
                DefaultTabController(
                  length: 2, // length of tabs
                  initialIndex: 0,
                  child: Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            child: TabBar( 
                                isScrollable: true,
                                
                  
                              labelColor: Colors.green,
                              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                              tabs: [
                                Tab(text: 'Expenses'),
                                Tab(text: 'Income'),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                              height:double.maxFinite, //height of TabBarView
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border(
                                      top: BorderSide(
                                          color: Colors.grey, width: 0.5))),
                              child: TabBarView(
                                
                                children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Text('Display Tab 1',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 22,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Text('Display Tab 2',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 22,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ]))
                        ]),
                  )),
                
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> After adding tabbar it gives me an error message
> " The relevant
> error-causing widget was Column lib\screens\books_page.dart:92 The
> overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical. The edge
> of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering
> with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the
> contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
>
> Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to
> force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space
> instead of being sized to their natural size. This is considered an
> error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot
> be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available
> space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it
> in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like
> a ListView. The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#20a41
> relayoutBoundary=up14 OVERFLOWING" How can I fix it?

Comment: I encountered a similar kind of error with CustomScrollView a while ago. The problem in my case was the fontSize of input text and hint text were different. Try setting these values to be the same explicitly and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your code to make it work. There were multiple parts that needed to change and I have marked them with comments:

I know giving the constant height of 200 might not be the best way, but I could not make it wrap its children. If you found a way for it, please let me know,it would be appreciated.

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class BooksPage extends StatefulWidget {
      const BooksPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<BooksPage> createState() => _BooksPageState();
    }
    
    class _BooksPageState extends State<BooksPage> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: Container(
            // ****** Add height here
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: SizedBox(
                // ****** Remove height from here
                // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      const Text(
                        "Hello",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        "Name Surname",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      const TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                        fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(244, 243, 243, 243),
                        filled: true,
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                        hintText: "Search the book",
                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 15, vertical: 17),
                      )),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          const Text(
                            "My books",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                          TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              child: Text(
                                "see more",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                              ))
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 260,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: 3,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                                width: 190,
                                height: 190,
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  // image: DecorationImage(
                                  //     image: AssetImage(
                                  //       "assets/images/pride.jpg",
                                  //     ),
                                  //     fit: BoxFit.fill),
                                ),
                              );
                            }),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      DefaultTabController(
                          length: 2, // length of tabs
                          initialIndex: 0,
                          // ****** Removed Expanded widget *********
                          child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  child: TabBar(
                                    isScrollable: true,
                                    labelColor: Colors.green,
                                    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                                    tabs: [
                                      Tab(text: 'Expenses'),
                                      Tab(text: 'Income'),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                    // ******** Add this height to the Container ********
                                    height: 200,
                                    // height: double.maxFinite, //height of TabBarView
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        border: Border(
                                            top: BorderSide(
                                                color: Colors.grey, width: 0.5))),
                                    child: TabBarView(children: <Widget>[
                                      Container(
                                        child: Center(
                                          child: Text('Display Tab 1',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 22,
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Container(
                                        child: Center(
                                          child: Text('Display Tab 2',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 22,
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ]))
                              ])),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

*(I removed the parts that needed the Constant.dart or image)*

Comment: Thank you. But it is not worked, it gives again error The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Comment: @TeddyBear I edited the answer, I was mixing up TabBarView with TabBar widget.